# How to best represent user actions in answers?

Tags: discussion

I monitor the SharePoint tag quite a lot and a number of answers instead of being code related instead need a numbered list of actions the user should perform. Typically I'll use the code tags to highlight the user action to help make my answers more readable, [here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31468320/add-a-webpart-to-a-publishing-page-layout/31468471#31468471) a good example of this.

My question is - should I be using these tags for this purpose or should these be exclusively reserved for code based answers? I feel that this stands out better then bold text would but I'm happy to change my approach if this isn't good practice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there is a right or wrong answer here. In your linked example, that looks good, the same effect could be achieved by [bolding](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/149533/1806) as well.  I think the delineation would be that if the answer includes code, to not code tag part of your answer as it would be too much and could cause it to be less readable. I think that anything that helps the user understand what the critical button, link, or action they need to take is helpful, which could be achieved by the code tag or the bold tag.

Comment: Excellent, that's a good way of looking at it. I just wanted to ensure that there wasn't a community approach that I should be adopting.